# Animación de texto en c#

Tags: c#

Necesito que mi programa aplique efecto maquina en un menú. Sin embargo, por mas que averiguo, no logró hacerlo..

```
internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        
            ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Menu menu = new Menu();
            menu.MenuPrincipal();
        }
       static void Escribir(int vel, Menu menu)
        {
            foreach (var item in menu)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
                Thread.Sleep(vel);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, y cómo es el efecto máquina del que hablas?

Comment: Es aquel en donde las letras se digitan  como si se estuviera escribiendo.... es decir, no te aparece todo el texto que vas a imprimir de un solo...

Comment: Podrías haber dicho eso desde el principio. Por cierto, cómo es que el código falla? No hay suficiente información como para inferir cuál es el tipo de `item`. No sabemos cuál es el código de la clase `Menu`.

Answer (score 1):

Efecto de escribir a maquina, verdad? Aquí tienes:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string helloWorld = "Hello World con espacios tambien";
        int velocidad = 300; // milisegundos
        for (int i = 0; i < helloWorld.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(helloWorld[i]);
            if (i + 1 < helloWorld.Length && helloWorld[i + 1] == ' ')
            {
                Console.Write(' ');
            }
            Thread.Sleep(velocidad);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: El código que me has brindado funciona, pero sólo para texto que son definido en la clase principal, y la idea es que funcione en un menú que está en otra clase y que se lea en la clase principal

Comment: Bienvenido ¿A caso lees mentes? La pregunta no aclara qué es el ***efecto máquina***. Evita responder preguntas incompletas.

Comment: @XaulerH... esto hace lo que vos queres.. que parte no entendiste???